# concept of different session in different window of same browser

Tags: java-me

how to prevent  user to relogin  in the same browser but different teb.Suppose i have loggid in gmail in a browser.But in the same browser in different tab ,if i login again, it will redirect me to the same page but my requirement is that it should redirect me to the gmail home page.Can any one solve this plz....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store two cookies, and you'll need a way to distinguish between the two cookies in the two sessions. The only way I know to do this is to encode part of the cookie in every single GET query made from a single "session".

Comment: But in a same browser ,the session and cookies are same.so how can i store two different cookie and session plz make me clear

Comment: @Debasish Bhadra: by encoding part of the session data in the GET string in the URL. So, all URLs coming from session one will contain `?s=1` at the end of the URL and all sessions coming from session two contains `?s=2`; something similar to that. Then, it doesn't matter if the browser sends two cookies since the server can use the GET data to determine whether to use `cookie-1` or `cookie-2`. There might be an easier way, but I don't currently know how.